# Is it safe to delete application registries?

Tags: windows-registry, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem that my VS crashes with the following message. One of my friends suggested to delete some of the registries related to VS and reinstall, But I want to know is it safe if I consider security?

[image: Crash message picture]

registries are

1. Delete the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version}`
2. Delete the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version}_Config`
3. Delete `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0` folder

Comment: can you explain us back which of the registry files your friend asked to delete,in which situation this error happening?

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 , they were added to the question, please check, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suspect a problem with VS2013, better first do a real uninstall,
only then clean the registry, and finally reinstall.

But if you have found a real bug in it, your only recourse is to
[file a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=26698).
But of course this will not fix your problem now (or ever).

Your options in this case are :

- Upgrade to a later version of VS in the hope that the bug was fixed
- Change your program until the bug goes away.